# Geometric Interpretation of GLS with endowment of new norm

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, least-squares

I was reading a very short passage about GLS (Generalized Least Squares Regression) provided with insufficient reference. I understand the derivation process of the BLUE $\hat{\beta_G} = (X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TV^{-1}Y$ where $var(\epsilon) = \sigma^2V$. What I don't understand is the derivation of the distribution of $\frac{SSE}{\sigma^2}$. The passage is given as below,

---

1. $X\hat{\beta_G}$ is the projection of Y onto $C_X$ when we endow $\mathbb{R^n}$ with a *new norm* $||\cdot||_{V^{-1}}$ defined by $||u||_{V^{-1}} = u^TV^{-1}u$
2. The projection properties of LSE are preserved, then we can attain the distribution of $\frac{SSE}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2(n-p-1)$

---

First of all, "Endowing" a new norm is a completely new thing for me. So what I tried was to show if this new norm suffices the basic conditions of norm, 1. non-negativity, 2. commutative property 3. triangular inequality. But I'm struggling to show number 3, do y'all think **Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality** can be any consolation?

Second, even if the norm is well-defined, how am I to show the projection properties of LSE are preserved?

Thank you.